# Combine rows with instruction from separate list

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to combine (SUM) rows with unique ID (column) numbers by specifying the ID numbers in a list and then make MYSQL combine rows in a table according to the specification in the list?

The data in the database I use change frequently changed but the customer ID that needs to be combined remains the same so it would be great if there was a a way to have the list in a separate file/table or similar to read form when I re-create the database with new values.

For example I want to combine ID 112 and 115 when I recreate the database to ID 112 with value 1 equal to 9 and value 2 equal to 12 (the sum of 112 and 115).

```
ID | VALUE 1  | VALUE 2
------------------------
...
112| 2       |5        
113| 5       |6
114| 6       |6
115| 7       |7
...
```

To new table:

```
ID | VALUE 1  | VALUE 2
------------------------
...
112| 9       |12        
113| 5       |6
114| 6       |6
...
```

This is sort of what I am looking for but is there a way to read the ID's from a list with several values? For example ( 112,115), ( 449,622), ( 123,423,321) etc.?

Something like:

```
select min(id) as newId, 
sum(value_1) as newValue1,
 sum(value_2) as newValue2
 from myTable t
```

where id in list;

How would the list need to be formatted?

Answer (score 0):

The following query should give you `112, 9, 12`

```
select min(id) as newId, 
       sum(value_1) as newValue1,
       sum(value_2) as newValue2
  from myTable t
 where id in ( 112,115);
```